# adding in props to obj without spreading

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to turn this:

```
  Map {
    0: { hangWithFriends: 100 },
    1: { Chill: 30, Book: 80 },
    2: { Yoga: 40 },
    3: { Birthday: 200 },
    4: { Gas: 70 },
    5: { Rent: 900, testingsub: 200 },
    6: { testSub: 500 }
  }
```

into this:

```
[
     {date: 0, hangWithFriends: 100}, 
     {date:1, Chill: 30, Book:80}, 
     {date: 2, Yoga:40}, 
     {date: 3, Birthday:200}, 
     {date:4, Gas:70},  
     {date:5, Rent:900, testingsub:200}, 
     {date: 6, testSub: 500}
]
```

I tried this:

```
  reducedMonths.forEach((date, obj) => {
    newData.push({ date, ...obj });
  });
```

But got this and I know it's because I'm spreading but I don't know how else to add a dynamic amount of props:

```
  Array(7) [
    { date: { hangWithFriends: 100 } }, 
    { date: { Chill: 30, Book: 80 } }, 
    { date: { Yoga: 40 } }, { date: { Birthday: 200 } },
    { date: { Gas: 70 } }, 
    { date: { Rent: 900, testingsub: 200 } }, 
    { date: { testSub: 500 } }
  ]
```

Comment: if you can't use spread. newObj = {date}; Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => newObj[key] = obj[key]). newData.push(newObj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could spread the map entries iterator into an array, and map the key to a parsed date integer and spread the values.

Make sure you sort the dates at the end, because sorting order is not guarenteed.

```js
const dataMap = new Map(Object.entries({
  '0': { 'hangWithFriends': 100 },
  '1': { 'Chill': 30, 'Book': 80 },
  '2': { 'Yoga': 40 },
  '3': { 'Birthday': 200 },
  '4': { 'Gas': 70 },
  '5': { 'Rent': 900, 'testingsub': 200 },
  '6': { 'testSub': 500 }
}));

const dataArr = [...dataMap.entries()]
  .map(([key, value]) => ({ date: +key, ...value }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
  
console.log(dataArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to optimize this, you can use an iterator to skip converting the entries into an array, prior to calling `Array.prototype.map`.

```js
const dataMap = new Map(Object.entries({
  '0': { 'hangWithFriends': 100 },
  '1': { 'Chill': 30, 'Book': 80 },
  '2': { 'Yoga': 40 },
  '3': { 'Birthday': 200 },
  '4': { 'Gas': 70 },
  '5': { 'Rent': 900, 'testingsub': 200 },
  '6': { 'testSub': 500 }
}));

const dataArr = [];

for (let [key, value] of dataMap) {
  dataArr.push({ date: +key, ...value });
}

dataArr.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date); // Make sure you sort

console.log(dataArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the optimized solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think this Snippet might help you

```js
const yourMap = {
  0: { hangWithFriends: 100 },
  1: { Chill: 30, Book: 80 },
  2: { Yoga: 40 },
  3: { Birthday: 200 },
  4: { Gas: 70 },
  5: { Rent: 900, testingsub: 200 },
  6: { testSub: 500 },
};

const transformedArray = Object.entries(yourMap).reduce((acc, [date, values]) => {
  const result = { date: parseInt(date, 10), ...values };
  acc.push(result);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(transformedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataMap = {
  '0': {
    'hangWithFriends': 100
  },
  '1': {
    'Chill': 30,
    'Book': 80
  },
  '2': {
    'Yoga': 40
  },
  '3': {
    'Birthday': 200
  },
  '4': {
    'Gas': 70
  },
  '5': {
    'Rent': 900,
    'testingsub': 200
  },
  '6': {
    'testSub': 500
  }
};

let data = [];
for (let x in dataMap) {
  let obj = {
    date: Number(x),
    ...dataMap[x]
  };
  data.push(obj);
};

console.log(data);
```